# Eclipse - limiting to-do only to certain files (or omit entire folders in project)

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to limit to-do in the task list to only certain files or omit certain folders?

Or, to rank the importance of the to-do task list?

Use-case:

I have a project using a bunch of Google libraries, except most of them are littered with to-do comments that I'd rather not have litter up the task list. Instead of search/replacing all those to-dos, I'd rather omit each library folder, or to select the files that are actually in my project, to list in todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the little arrow on the right of the task view and click : `Configure Contents`.

From this menu you can change the scope of the task view to the current selected project or reconfigure it completely to match your usecase.

Comment: Thanks - limiting by working sets lets me de-include folders to omit from the To-Do task list.